# how to get some specific elements of a list? the ones who start with 4 digit and the first 0, and some lines after that?

Tags: python, list, text

I have a text and I need to extract some information from it. it is a list actually see a part of my text below:

```
 lines=[   '0021   Literacy and numeracy \n',
 '\n',
 'Literacy and numeracy are programmes or qualifications arranged mainly for adults, designed \n',
 'to  teach  fundamental  skills  in  reading,  writing  and  arithmetic.  The  typical  age  range  of \n',
 'participants  can  be  used  to  distinguish  between  detailed  field  0011  ‘Basic  programmes  and \n',
 'qualifications’ and this detailed field.  \n',
 '\n',
 'Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here: \n',
 '\n',
'0031   Personal skills \n',
 '\n',
 'Personal  skills  are  defined  by  reference  to  the  effects  on  the  individual’s  capacity  (mental, \n',
 'social  etc.).  This  detailed  field  covers  personal  skills  programmes  not  included  in  0011  ‘Basic \n',
 'programmes and qualifications’ or 0021 ‘Literacy and numeracy’, giving key competencies and \n',
 'transferable skills.  \n',
 '\n',
 'Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here: \n',
 '\n']
```

The output is two list:

1- I wanna collect all lines started by 4 digit (the first digit is 0 always) also 2- a paragraph after that. Note that a paragraph can be in different item of list. each element of the list is a line in my text. so a paragraph finish when I get to `\n` (so it is a nested list). here is the output that I wanna get:

```
G= [ ['0021   Literacy and numeracy \n','0031   Personal skills \n']

G1=[['Literacy and numeracy are programmes or qualifications arranged mainly for adults, designed \n',
     'to  teach  fundamental  skills  in  reading,  writing  and  arithmetic.  The  typical  age  range  of \n',
     'participants  can  be  used  to  distinguish  between  detailed  field  0011  ‘Basic  programmes  and \n',
     'qualifications’ and this detailed field.  \n'], ['Personal  skills  are  defined  by  reference  to  the  effects  on  the  individual’s  capacity  (mental, \n',
 'social  etc.).  This  detailed  field  covers  personal  skills  programmes  not  included  in  0011  ‘Basic \n',
 'programmes and qualifications’ or 0021 ‘Literacy and numeracy’, giving key competencies and \n',
 'transferable skills.  \n',
 '\n',]]
```

Here is what I tried but I really don't know why it doesn't work!

```
    definition=[]
    ocupation=[]
    for l,i in enumerate(lines):
       if re.findall(r'd\d\d\d',i)!='':
            ocupation.append(i)
            for j in range(10):
                def1=[]
                while lines[l+2+j]!='\n':
                    def1.append(lines[l+j])
            definition.append(def1)
```

this line `if re.findall(r'd\d\d\d',i)!='':` doesn't work well. I want 4 digit to be at the beginning and start by 0, but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [
    '0021   Literacy and numeracy \n',
    '\n',
    'Literacy and numeracy are programmes or qualifications arranged mainly for adults, designed \n',
    'to  teach  fundamental  skills  in  reading,  writing  and  arithmetic.  The  typical  age  range  of \n',
    'participants  can  be  used  to  distinguish  between  detailed  field  0011  ‘Basic  programmes  and \n',
    'qualifications’ and this detailed field.  \n',
    '\n',
    'Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here: \n',
    '\n',
    '0031   Personal skills \n',
    '\n',
    'Personal  skills  are  defined  by  reference  to  the  effects  on  the  individual’s  capacity  (mental, \n',
    'social  etc.).  This  detailed  field  covers  personal  skills  programmes  not  included  in  0011  ‘Basic \n',
    'programmes and qualifications’ or 0021 ‘Literacy and numeracy’, giving key competencies and \n',
    'transferable skills.  \n',
    '\n',
    'Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here: \n',
    '\n']
definition = []
ocupation = []
for l, i in enumerate(lines):
    if i[:4].isnumeric():
        ocupation.append(i)
        def1 = []
        for j in lines[l+2:]:
            if j == '\n':
                break
            def1.append(j)
        definition.append(def1)

print(ocupation, definition, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
['0021   Literacy and numeracy \n', '0031   Personal skills \n']
[['Literacy and numeracy are programmes or qualifications arranged mainly for adults, designed \n', 'to  teach  fundamental  skills  in  reading,  writing  and  arithmetic.  The  typical  age  range  of \n', 'participants  can  be  used  to  distinguish  between  detailed  field  0011  ‘Basic  programmes  and \n', 'qualifications’ and this detailed field.  \n'], ['Personal  skills  are  defined  by  reference  to  the  effects  on  the  individual’s  capacity  (mental, \n', 'social  etc.).  This  detailed  field  covers  personal  skills  programmes  not  included  in  0011  ‘Basic \n', 'programmes and qualifications’ or 0021 ‘Literacy and numeracy’, giving key competencies and \n', 'transferable skills.  \n']]
```

Comment: thank you. occupation works great but definition is an empty list (it has just one element as `\n`). can u see why?

Comment: See I've editted & made it simpler, you may try.

Answer (score 0):

I run through your code,try my best to make less changes.I do not provide a new solution because I want you know more about what's the problem in the code,maybe some help for your learning code.

```py
lines=[   '0021   Literacy and numeracy \n',
 '\n',
 'Literacy and numeracy are programmes or qualifications arranged mainly for adults, designed \n',
 'to  teach  fundamental  skills  in  reading,  writing  and  arithmetic.  The  typical  age  range  of \n',
 'participants  can  be  used  to  distinguish  between  detailed  field  0011  ‘Basic  programmes  and \n',
 'qualifications’ and this detailed field.  \n',
 '\n',
 'Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here: \n',
 '\n',
'0031   Personal skills \n',
 '\n',
 'Personal  skills  are  defined  by  reference  to  the  effects  on  the  individual’s  capacity  (mental, \n',
 'social  etc.).  This  detailed  field  covers  personal  skills  programmes  not  included  in  0011  ‘Basic \n',
 'programmes and qualifications’ or 0021 ‘Literacy and numeracy’, giving key competencies and \n',
 'transferable skills.  \n',
 '\n',
 'Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here: \n',
 '\n']

import re
definition=[]
ocupation=[]
for l,i in enumerate(lines):
    #the findall always return match group,if not match the group will be 0
    #so make it easy we can use match,and the regex can replace with '\d{4}'
    if re.match(r'\d\d\d\d',i) is not None:
        ocupation.append(i)

        #should init variable before for loop
        def1=[]
        for j in range(2,10):
            #in your case the 6th line is a '\n' too,so I change the test case to double '\n'
            if lines[l+j] == '\n' and lines[l+j+2] == '\n':
                break
            #bypass any '\n'
            elif lines[l+j]=='\n':
                continue
            else:
                def1.append(lines[l+j])
        definition.append(def1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified and debugged your code as much as I could and thought of adding a new answer, try this:

```
lines = [
    '0021   Literacy and numeracy \n',
    '\n',
    'Literacy and numeracy are programmes or qualifications arranged mainly for adults, designed \n',
    'to  teach  fundamental  skills  in  reading,  writing  and  arithmetic.  The  typical  age  range  of \n',
    'participants  can  be  used  to  distinguish  between  detailed  field  0011  ‘Basic  programmes  and \n',
    'qualifications’ and this detailed field.  \n',
    '\n',
    'Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here: \n',
    '\n',
    '0031   Personal skills \n',
    '\n',
    'Personal  skills  are  defined  by  reference  to  the  effects  on  the  individual’s  capacity  (mental, \n',
    'social  etc.).  This  detailed  field  covers  personal  skills  programmes  not  included  in  0011  ‘Basic \n',
    'programmes and qualifications’ or 0021 ‘Literacy and numeracy’, giving key competencies and \n',
    'transferable skills.  \n',
    '\n',
    'Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here: \n',
    '\n']
definition = []
ocupation = []
for l, i in enumerate(lines):
    if i[:4].isnumeric():
        ocupation += [i]
        definition += [lines[l+2:lines.index('\n', l+2)] if '\n' in lines[l+2:] else lines[l+2:]]
print(ocupation, definition, sep='\n')
```